# header and footer repeating at the end page in the doc while rendering Visualforce as Ms Word document

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, ms-word

I have searched solution for this and got the solution only to move that repeated header and footer out of the page to hide that. But I don't want to do that, can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance, have a great day.
this is my code.

```
<apex:page Controller="cls"  showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" contentType="application/msword#DirectCustomerOffer.doc"  sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false"   standardStylesheets="false"  >
    <html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='<a target="_blank" href="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" rel="nofollow">http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40</a>' > <!--xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" contentType="application/msword" contentType="application/msword#DirectCustomerOffer.doc"-->
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
            <style>
                @page Section1{
                size:8.5in 11.0in; 
                margin:0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;
                mso-header-margin:0.5in;
                mso-header:h1;
                mso-footer:f1; 
                mso-footer-margin:0.5in;
                mso-paper-source:0;
                }
                div.Section1{
                page:Section1;
                }
                /*Below is the style to prevent the repetition of header and Footer.. Cheers!!!*/
                table#hrdftrtbl{
                margin:0in 0in 0in 10.5in;
                }        
                .column {
                float: left;
                width: 50% !important;
                }
                
                .row:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
                }
                
                
                
                
                
                @page Main {
                mso-header:h1;
                mso-footer:f1;
                }
                div.Main{
                page:Main;
                }
                p.MyFoot, li.MyFoot, div.MyFoot{
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                tab-stops:center 216.0pt right 432.0pt;
                }
                div#f1{
                margin:0in 0in 0in 10.5in;
                }
                div#h1{
                margin:0in 0in 0in 10.5in;
                }
                p.MyHead {
                
                }
            </style>
            <!--Header to display logo and Information  -->
            
        </head>
        
        <!--Body to display all the Information of the template id='hrdftrtbl'-->  
        <body>
            <div class="Section1">
                
                <p style="font-family:Calibri;text-align: left;font-size:13.5;"><apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}"><apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> </apex:outputText> <br/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Some content 
                </p> 
                <!-- Footer -->
                <div class="Main">
                    <div style="mso-element:header" id="h1">
                        <p class="MyHead">
                            <table  border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <!--Header-->
                                        <!--div style='mso-element:header' id="h1" >
<p class="MsoHeader"-->
                                        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="20%" valign="top">
                                                    header left
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center" width="60%">
                                                    header center
                                                    <br/> 
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="right" width="20%">
                                                    <!--<img src="{!$Label.Phoenix_DRL_Address_Url}" width="150px"  height="80px" /><br/> -->
                                                    <p style="float: right;width: 50%;font-family:Calibri;text-align: right;font-size:10.5;color: #7030a0; margin-right: 0">
                                                        header right</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>  </td></tr></table>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </p><br/>
                </div>
                <div style="mso-element:footer" id="f1">
                    <p class="MyFoot">
                        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" valign="top">
                                    <span style="font-family:Calibri;text-align: left;font-size:13.5;">
                                        footer first table
                                    </span><br/>
                                </td>    
                                
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" valign="top">
                                footer second table left
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" width="60%">
                                footer second table right
                                <br/> 
                            </td>
                            
                            <td align="right" width="20%">
                                footer second table right</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>  
                </p></div>
        </div>    
        <!-- Footer Ends -->
    </body> 
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, here's the solution that worked for me:

```
<table id='hrdftrtbl' ><!--The table+id='hrdftrtbl' tag makes the header/footer not repeat at the end of the doc-->
   Footer or Header
</table>
```